# How to extract an element from an array in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have a data frame with following type:

```
col1|col2|col3|col4
xxxx|yyyy|zzzz|[1111],[2222]
```

I want my output to be of the following type:

```
col1|col2|col3|col4|col5
xxxx|yyyy|zzzz|1111|2222
```

My `col4` is an array, and I want to convert it into a separate column. What needs to be done?

I saw many answers with `flatMap`, but they are increasing a row. I want the tuple to be put in another column but in the same row.

The following is my current schema:

```
root
 |-- PRIVATE_IP: string (nullable = true)
 |-- PRIVATE_PORT: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- DESTINATION_IP: string (nullable = true)
 |-- DESTINATION_PORT: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- collect_set(TIMESTAMP): array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

Also, can please someone help me with explanation on both dataframes and RDD's.

Comment: What's the schema of your data frame? Can you show df.printSchema()?

Comment: Hi, I edited the question with my actual schema

Comment: Does all cells in the array column have the same number of elements? Always 2? What if another row have three elements in the array?

Comment: No all the elements have exactly 2 elements. Because the element in the array are a start date and end date.

Comment: Also this is my actual requirment if you can help me with it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45252906/combine-two-rows-in-spark-based-on-a-condition-in-pyspark?noredirect=1#comment77471048_45252906

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Create sample data:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
x = [Row(col1="xx", col2="yy", col3="zz", col4=[123,234])]
rdd = sc.parallelize([Row(col1="xx", col2="yy", col3="zz", col4=[123,234])])
df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd)
df.show()
#+----+----+----+----------+
#|col1|col2|col3|      col4|
#+----+----+----+----------+
#|  xx|  yy|  zz|[123, 234]|
#+----+----+----+----------+
```

Use `getItem` to extract element from the array column as this, in your actual case replace `col4` with `collect_set(TIMESTAMP)`:

```
df = df.withColumn("col5", df["col4"].getItem(1)).withColumn("col4", df["col4"].getItem(0))
df.show()
#+----+----+----+----+----+
#|col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|
#+----+----+----+----+----+
#|  xx|  yy|  zz| 123| 234|
#+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Comment: @Lydia please be *extremely careful* and sure you know what you are doing when altering code: your edit had ruined a perfectly good answer, leading it to throw an exception (restored it to OP's original)...

Comment: Do you have a way to generalize the iteration over the original col4's array ?

Comment: @Amesys Did you try destructuring a list comprehension ?

Comment: I have a follow-up question, dropping the link, thanks in advance! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61823544/pyspark-mapping-multiple-columns @Psidom

Comment: What is efficient way to apply this to more than 10 columns but each column has only one item in list

Answer (score 9):

You have 4 options to extract the value inside the array:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([[1, [10, 20, 30, 40]]], ['A', 'B'])
df.show()

+---+----------------+
|  A|               B|
+---+----------------+
|  1|[10, 20, 30, 40]|
+---+----------------+

from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.select(
    "A",
    df.B[0].alias("B0"), # dot notation and index        
    F.col("B")[1].alias("B1"), # function col and index
    df.B.getItem(2).alias("B2"), # dot notation and method getItem
    F.col("B").getItem(3).alias("B3"), # function col and method getItem
).show()

+---+---+---+---+---+
|  A| B0| B1| B2| B3|
+---+---+---+---+---+
|  1| 10| 20| 30| 40|
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

In case you have many columns, use a list comprehension:

```
df.select(
    'A', *[F.col('B')[i].alias(f'B{i}') for i in range(4)]
).show()

+---+---+---+---+---+
|  A| B0| B1| B2| B3|
+---+---+---+---+---+
|  1| 10| 20| 30| 40|
+---+---+---+---+---+
```