# PySpark create new column from existing column with a list of values

Tags: python, pyspark

I've got a DataFrame like this:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import Row

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName('DataFrame') \
    .master('local[*]') \
    .getOrCreate()

df = spark.createDataFrame([Row(a=1, b='', c=['0', '1'], d='foo'),
                            Row(a=2, b='', c=['0', '1'], d='bar'),
                            Row(a=3, b='', c=['0', '1'], d='foo')])

|  a|  b|     c|  d|
+---+---+------+---+
|  1|   |[0, 1]|foo|
|  2|   |[0, 1]|bar|
|  3|   |[0, 1]|foo|
+---+---+------+---+
```

I would like to create column `"e"` with first element of `"c"` column and `"f"` column with second element of `"c"` column", to look like this:

```
|a  |b  |c     |d  |e  |f  |
+---+---+------+---+---+---+
|1  |   |[0, 1]|foo|0  |1  |
|2  |   |[0, 1]|bar|0  |1  |
|3  |   |[0, 1]|foo|0  |1  |
+---+---+------+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract an element from a array in pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45254928/how-to-extract-an-element-from-a-array-in-pyspark)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([Row(a=1, b='', c=['0', '1'], d='foo'),
                            Row(a=2, b='', c=['0', '1'], d='bar'),
                            Row(a=3, b='', c=['0', '1'], d='foo')])

df2 = df.withColumn('e', df['c'][0]).withColumn('f', df['c'][1])
df2.show()

+---+---+------+---+---+---+
|a  |b  |c     |d  |e  |f  |
+---+---+------+---+---+---+
|1  |   |[0, 1]|foo|0  |1  |
|2  |   |[0, 1]|bar|0  |1  |
|3  |   |[0, 1]|foo|0  |1  |
+---+---+------+---+---+---+
```