# PySpark: extract/collect first array element from a column

Tags: python, arrays, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe that looks like

```
 |-- alleleFrequencies: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
```

`element` is an array of doubles

I wish to get this data into a `numpy` array, which I have naively done thus:

```
allele_freq1 = np.array(df1.select("alleleFrequencies").collect())
```

but this gives

```
[[list([0.5, 0.5])]
 [list([0.5, 0.5])]
 [list([1.0])]...
```

which isn't a simple 1D array like what I want

I've also tried

```
allele_freq1 = np.array(df1.select("alleleFrequencies")[0].collect())
```

but this gives

```
TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable
```

I've also tried

```
allele_freq1 = np.array(df1.select("alleleFrequencies[0]").collect())
```

but this gives

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve &#39;`alleleFrequencies[0]`&#39; given input columns...
```

How can I get the first item in the column `alleleFrequencies` placed into a `numpy` array?

I checked [How to extract an element from a array in pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45254928/how-to-extract-an-element-from-a-array-in-pyspark) but I don't see how the solution there applies to my situation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract an element from a array in pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45254928/how-to-extract-an-element-from-a-array-in-pyspark)

Comment: @pault the first you give gives an error that it cannot resolve the column name, and the link you gave gives no useful information

Comment: ok then use `pyspark.sql.functions.col` and `getItem` (as shown in the link I gave): `np.array(df1.select(col("alleleFrequencies").getItem(0)).collect())`. *no useful information* is a pretty broad statement.

Comment: thanks @pault the last comment `pyspark.sql.functions.col: np.array(df1.select(col("alleleFrequencies").getItem(0)).collect())` gets the job done

Comment: That's exactly what's contained in the duplicate I linked. I bet `selectExpr` would probably work here too: `np.array(df1.selectExpr("alleleFrequencies[0]").collect())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
allele_freq1 = np.array(df1.select(col("alleleFrequencies").getItem(0)).collect())
print(allele_freq1)
print(type(allele_freq1))
```