# Parse json with same key to different columns

Tags: pyspark

Schema of my json is next

[image]

and field `Reports_Rows_Rows_Cells` if it not null  looks like next:

```
[Row(Attributes=[Row(Id='account', Value='bd9e85e0-0478-433d-ae9f-0b3c4f04bfe4')], Value='Business Bank Account'),
 Row(Attributes=[Row(Id='account', Value='bd9e85e0-0478-433d-ae9f-0b3c4f04bfe4')], Value='10105.54'),
 Row(Attributes=[Row(Id='account', Value='bd9e85e0-0478-433d-ae9f-0b3c4f04bfe4')], Value='4938.48')]
```

What I want is to create table which has all above columns and column `Reports_Rows_Rows_Cells` should look like

```
-------- |-------|Reports_Rows_Rows_Cells_Value | Reports_Rows_Rows_Cells_Value | Reports_Rows_Rows_Cells_Value|
                 | Business Bank Account        |10105.54                       | 4938.48
```

Not after parsing json my table look like next:

```
-------- |-------|Reports_Rows_Rows_Cells_Value|
                 | Business Bank Account       |
                 | 10105.54                    |
                 | 4938.48                     |
```

My code which I use to parse json

```
def flatten_df(nested_df):
    # for ncol in nested_df.columns:
    array_cols = [c[0] for c in nested_df.dtypes if c[1][:5] == 'array']
    for col in array_cols:
        nested_df = nested_df.withColumn(col, explode_outer(nested_df[col]))
    nested_cols = [c[0] for c in nested_df.dtypes if c[1][:6] == 'struct']
    if len(nested_cols) == 0:
        return nested_df
    flat_cols = [c[0] for c in nested_df.dtypes if c[1][:6] != 'struct']
    flat_df = nested_df.select(flat_cols + 
                                [F.col(nc+'.'+c).alias(nc+'_'+c) 
                                for nc in nested_cols
                                for c in nested_df.select(nc+'.*').columns])
    return flatten_df(flat_df)
```

Comment: can you show your code ?

Comment: Steven I changed question and added code.Can you see?

Comment: You can directly unpack the array as shown here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45254928/how-to-extract-an-element-from-a-array-in-pyspark